# Deadlocked in w3wp for a WCF website. Unable to find source of Issue

Tags: wcf, clr, deadlock, windbg, w3wp

I have a wcf application that frequently hangs and the clients keep getting timed out.I did a windbg trace and it detected a deadlock. However, the deadlock seems to be in unmanaged code and i am not able to dig any further.
Please help. Here is the WindDBG trace:

```
!dlk
Scanning for ReaderWriterLock instances...
Scanning for holders of ReaderWriterLock locks...
Scanning for ReaderWriterLockSlim instances...
Scanning for holders of ReaderWriterLockSlim locks...
Examining CriticalSections...
Scanning for threads waiting on SyncBlocks...
Scanning for threads waiting on ReaderWriterLock locks...
Scanning for threads waiting on ReaderWriterLocksSlim locks...
Scanning for threads waiting on CriticalSections...
*DEADLOCK DETECTED*
CLR thread 0x37 holds CriticalSection 000000000d5c88e0
...and is waiting on CriticalSection 000000000e88c9b0
CLR thread 0x2e holds CriticalSection 000000000e88c9b0
...and is waiting on CriticalSection 000000000d5c88e0
CLR Thread 0x37 is waiting at clr!CrstBase::Enter+0x111
CLR Thread 0x2e is waiting at clr!CrstBase::Enter+0x111
```

Of the 2 threads i understand the clrstack of one thread( which is stuck at managed code)  but not the other. 
Here is the dumpstack for thread where i have no idea what is happening.
It will be great if somebody could tell what this thread is doing.

```
Child-SP         RetAddr          Caller, Callee
000000000da2abb0 00000000775c53ea ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0xea, calling ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject
000000000da2ac00 00000000770f5eca kernel32!SwitchToThread+0xa, calling ntdll!NtYieldExecution
000000000da2ac30 000007fef5a59090 clr!__DangerousSwitchToThread+0x50, calling kernel32!SwitchToThread
000000000da2ac60 00000000775c52e1 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0xf4, calling ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection
000000000da2ac90 000007fef5abdd38 clr!CrstBase::Enter+0x111, calling clr!CrstBase::SpinEnter
000000000da2acc0 000007fef5a52b83 clr!CrstBase::CrstHolder::CrstHolder+0x14, calling clr!CrstBase::Enter
000000000da2acf0 000007fef5c458a8 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeHandleForTypeKey_Body+0x817, calling clr!CrstBase::CrstHolder::CrstHolder
000000000da2ad80 000007fef5acc7b7 clr!FieldSecurityDescriptor::VerifyDataComputed+0x342, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000000da2ae20 000007fef5abd8b5 clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing+0x25d, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000000da2ae30 000007fef5ac9999 clr!MDInternalRO::GetNestedClassProps+0x59
000000000da2af40 000007fef5ac4c83 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeHandleForTypeKey+0xf5, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeHandleForTypeKey_Body
000000000da2afe0 000007fef5b9f297 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefThrowing+0x23b, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeHandleForTypeKey
000000000da2aff0 000007fef5aca594 clr!ClassLoader::CheckAccessMember+0x148
000000000da2b080 000007fef5c59bd6 clr!CEEInfo::getFieldInfo+0x10dd, calling clr!ClassLoader::CanAccessClass
000000000da2b0c0 000007fef5af57e2 clr!MethodTableBuilder::SetContextfulOrByRef+0x96, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000000da2b140 000007fef5af377c clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing+0x39b, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefThrowing
000000000da2b1f0 000007fef5afb687 clr!MethodTableBuilder::ValidateInterfaceMethodConstraints+0x357, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000000da2b270 000007fef5abd873 clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing+0x1e0, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing
000000000da2b2b0 000007fef5abd8b5 clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing+0x25d, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000000da2b3a0 000007fef5b3355f clr!TypeHandle::SatisfiesClassConstraints+0x6b, calling clr!TypeHandle::HasInstantiation
000000000da2b420 000007fef5bb8907 clr!CMiniMdRW::vSearchTable+0x67
000000000da2b460 000007fef5af4bd2 clr!validateOneArg+0x14d
000000000da2b470 000007fef5adaf68 clr!SigPointer::PeekValueTypeTokenClosed+0xa0, calling clr!CorSigUncompressData
000000000da2b4d0 000007fef5a7a64f clr!MethodTableBuilder::InitializeFieldDescs+0x701, calling clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing
000000000da2b730 000007fef5af8b8f clr!MethodTableBuilder::AllocAndInitMethodDescs+0x16c, calling clr!MethodTableBuilder::AllocAndInitMethodDescChunk
000000000da2b7a0 000007fef5af65a5 clr!MethodTableBuilder::BuildMethodTableThrowing+0x698, calling clr!MethodTableBuilder::InitializeFieldDescs
000000000da2b930 000007fef5ac9999 clr!MDInternalRO::GetNestedClassProps+0x59
000000000da2b980 000007fef5af5e8a clr!ClassLoader::CreateTypeHandleForTypeDefThrowing+0x44e, calling clr!MethodTableBuilder::BuildMethodTableThrowing
000000000da2bbc0 00000000775ec1ce ntdll!RtlpDeCommitFreeBlock+0x5a, calling ntdll!RtlpInsertFreeBlock
000000000da2bc60 000007fef5af3bd3 clr!IsStackWalkerThread+0xc, calling clr!ClrFlsGetBlock
000000000da2bca0 000007fef5ac53f5 clr!ClassLoader::CreateTypeHandleForTypeKey+0x5d, calling clr!ClassLoader::CreateTypeHandleForTypeDefThrowing
000000000da2bd30 000007fef945c580 clrjit!ReaderBase::readBytesForFlowGraphNode+0x1b0, calling clrjit!ReaderBase::readBytesForFlowGraphNode_Helper
000000000da2bd40 000007fef5b33005 clr!CEEInfo::setMethodAttribs+0x1a3, calling clr!MethodDesc::InterlockedUpdateFlags
000000000da2bd90 000007fef5ac5365 clr!ClassLoader::DoIncrementalLoad+0x6d, calling clr!ClassLoader::CreateTypeHandleForTypeKey
000000000da2be60 000007fef5af3bd3 clr!IsStackWalkerThread+0xc, calling clr!ClrFlsGetBlock
000000000da2be70 000007fef946334b clrjit!THX_dop2_ReadProc+0x7f, calling clrjit!IMetaYieldExecution
000000000da2be80 00000000775c584a ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+0x9a, calling ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection
000000000da2bec0 00000000775e870a ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0xe2, calling ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext
000000000da2bf90 000007fef5acee7d clr!CEEInfo::ConvToJitSig+0x26a, calling clr!SigParser::SkipExactlyOne
000000000da2bff0 000007fef5ac4e4c clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeHandleForTypeKey_Body+0x378, calling clr!ClassLoader::DoIncrementalLoad
000000000da2c0c0 000007fef5af3dfd clr!Assembly::FindModuleByTypeRef+0x1a2, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000000da2c0f0 000007fef5bba155 clr!MDInternalRW::GetNameOfTypeDef+0xfd
000000000da2c110 000007fef5a5a216 clr!ConstructKeyCallbackCompare::UseKeys+0x64, calling MSVCR120_CLR0400!strcmp
000000000da2c140 000007fef5a5a1b7 clr!EEClassHashTable::ConstructKeyFromData+0xec, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000000da2c180 000007fef5a59d04 clr!NgenHashTable<EEClassHashTable,EEClassHashEntry,4>::FindPersistedEntryByHash+0x55, calling clr!NgenHashTable<StubMethodHashTable,StubMethodHashEntry,2>::PersistedBucketList::GetBucket
000000000da2c1d0 000007fef5af3948 clr!ClassLoader::GetClassValue+0x252, calling clr!EEClassHashTable::ConstructKeyFromData
000000000da2c240 000007fef5ac4c83 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeHandleForTypeKey+0xf5, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeHandleForTypeKey_Body
000000000da2c2e0 000007fef5b9f297 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefThrowing+0x23b, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeHandleForTypeKey
000000000da2c340 000007fef5a5a1b7 clr!EEClassHashTable::ConstructKeyFromData+0xec, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000000da2c380 000007fef5a5a630 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeHandleThrowing+0x14f, calling clr!TypeHandle::GetLoadLevel
000000000da2c3d0 000007fef5af3948 clr!ClassLoader::GetClassValue+0x252, calling clr!EEClassHashTable::ConstructKeyFromData
000000000da2c440 000007fef5af377c clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing+0x39b, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefThrowing
000000000da2c570 000007fef5abd873 clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing+0x1e0, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing
000000000da2c640 000007fef5c58bab clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing+0x4f3, calling clr!LookupMapBase::GetElementPtr
000000000da2c770 000007fef5ac1a6a clr!SigPointer::GetGenericInstType+0x143, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing
000000000da2c7d0 000007fef5ac16c9 clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing+0x564, calling clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing
000000000da2c7f0 000007fef5a5e906 clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing+0x4f2, calling clr!_chkstk
000000000da2c970 000007fef5abe5fe clr!CExecutionEngine::AcquireLock+0x9b, calling ntdll!RtlTryEnterCriticalSection
000000000da2c990 000007fef5ac8d32 clr!MethodTable::MethodDataObject::`vector deleting destructor'+0x3a, calling clr!EEHeapFreeInProcessHeap
000000000da2ca00 000007fef5acaaea clr!MDInternalRO::GetTypeSpecFromToken+0xa6
000000000da2ca50 000007fef5ad8ddb clr!MemberLoader::GetDescFromMemberRef+0x62a, calling clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing
000000000da2cd80 000007fef5ad19d9 clr!CEEInfo::resolveToken+0x7fc, calling clr!MemberLoader::GetDescFromMemberRef
000000000da2cf10 000007fef5acc7ed clr!FieldSecurityDescriptor::IsTreatAsSafe+0xe, calling clr!FieldSecurityDescriptor::VerifyDataComputed
000000000da2cfd0 000007fef5c59bd6 clr!CEEInfo::getFieldInfo+0x10dd, calling clr!ClassLoader::CanAccessClass
000000000da2cff0 000007fef5acee7d clr!CEEInfo::ConvToJitSig+0x26a, calling clr!SigParser::SkipExactlyOne
000000000da2d090 000007fef5acee7d clr!CEEInfo::ConvToJitSig+0x26a, calling clr!SigParser::SkipExactlyOne
000000000da2d170 000007fef5acecf8 clr!CEEInfo::getMethodSig+0x36b, calling clr!CEEInfo::ConvToJitSig
000000000da2d210 000007fef5acecf8 clr!CEEInfo::getMethodSig+0x36b, calling clr!CEEInfo::ConvToJitSig
000000000da2d2b0 000007fef94b65d4 clrjit!ReaderBase::getCallSiteSignature+0x50, calling clrjit!CORINFO_SIG_INFO::isVarArg
000000000da2d2e0 000007fef94e99c4 clrjit!ReaderBase::VerifyIsMethodToken+0x14, calling clrjit!ReaderBase::VerifyToken
000000000da2d2f0 000007fef94d6279 clrjit!ReaderBase::getCallSiteSignature+0x29, calling clrjit!ReaderBase::getCallSiteSignature
000000000da2d350 000007fef9461ac5 clrjit!GenIR::GenIR_FgCall+0x334
000000000da2d470 000007fef945e512 clrjit!ReaderBase::fgBuildPhase1+0x2a2
000000000da2d540 000007fef945897b clrjit!ReaderBase::fgBuildBasicBlocksFromBytes+0x8b, calling clrjit!ReaderBase::fgBuildPhase1
000000000da2d590 000007fef945f3d6 clrjit!ReaderBase::buildFlowGraph+0x26, calling clrjit!ReaderBase::fgBuildBasicBlocksFromBytes
000000000da2d5c0 000007fef94602cc clrjit!ReaderBase::MSILToIR+0x9c, calling clrjit!ReaderBase::buildFlowGraph
000000000da2d620 000007fef9463308 clrjit!THX_dop2_ReadProc+0x48, calling clrjit!ReaderBase::MSILToIR
000000000da2d780 000007fef946475f clrjit!InitCompilerInstance+0x46f, calling clrjit!THX_NColMdInitialize
000000000da2d7e0 000007fef94642c9 clrjit!JitContext::GetContext+0x124, calling clrjit!InitCompilerInstance
000000000da2d7f0 000007fef9457d8c clrjit!THX_dop2+0x8c, calling clrjit!THX_dop2_ReadProc
000000000da2d870 000007fef946410b clrjit!PreJit::compileMethod+0x67, calling clrjit!PreJit::jitCompile
000000000da2d8f0 000007fef5a7f643 clr!invokeCompileMethodHelper+0x7f
000000000da2d910 000007fef5acbb99 clr!ClassLoader::CanAccessClass+0x176
000000000da2d940 000007fef5a7f56f clr!invokeCompileMethod+0x8f, calling clr!invokeCompileMethodHelper
000000000da2d990 000007fef5a80d4b clr!EEJitManager::setBoundaries+0x986, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000000da2d9b0 000007fef5a7f45e clr!CallCompileMethodWithSEHWrapper+0x46, calling clr!invokeCompileMethod
000000000da2da10 00000000770fa47f kernel32!QueryPerformanceCounter+0xf, calling ntdll!ZwQueryPerformanceCounter
000000000da2da40 000007fef5a7f325 clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0x9bb, calling clr!CallCompileMethodWithSEHWrapper
000000000da2dbc0 00000000775eaf41 ntdll!RtlpFreeHeap+0x9df, calling ntdll!RtlpDeCommitFreeBlock
000000000da2dd30 000007fef9473f04 clrjit!THX_makeEA+0x18c, calling clrjit!THX_immed
000000000da2de50 000007fef5ac8683 clr!TokenSecurityDescriptor::ReadSecurityAttributes+0xa3, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000000da2de90 000007fef5abd8b5 clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing+0x25d, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000000da2dee0 00000000775e8b85 ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x1a2, calling ntdll!RtlpFreeHeap
000000000da2df50 000007fef5acdd28 clr!MethodSecurityDescriptor::ComputeCriticalTransparentInfo+0x468, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000000da2dfb0 000007fef5a53605 clr!MetaSig::Init+0xc4, calling clr!SigParser::SkipExactlyOne
000000000da2dfc0 000007fef9454a14 clrjit!operator delete+0x14, calling clr!EEHeapFreeInProcessHeap
000000000da2e020 000007fef5ace690 clr!Module::GetIL+0x41, calling clr!PEDecoder::CheckILMethod
000000000da2e050 000007fef5ac2909 clr!ClassLoader::CanAccessClass+0x99, calling clr!MethodTable::GetAssembly
000000000da2e0a0 000007fef5b33208 clr!MethodDesc::IsVerifiable+0xb0, calling clr!UnsafeJitFunction
000000000da2e140 000007fef5b333ff clr!IsTransparentMethodSafeToSkipVerification+0x8c, calling clr!MethodDesc::IsVerifiable
000000000da2e1f0 000007fef5b32fcf clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0xd5e, calling clr!IsTransparentMethodSafeToSkipVerification
000000000da2e240 000007fef5ac692d clr!MethodTableBuilder::CopyExactParentSlots+0x2cd
000000000da2e600 000007fef5ac6287 clr!MethodTable::DoFullyLoad+0x5e0, calling clr!MethodTable::SetIsFullyLoaded
000000000da2e6e0 00000000775c584a ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+0x9a, calling ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection
000000000da2e720 00000000775e870a ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0xe2, calling ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext
000000000da2e750 00000000775c56e3 ntdll!RtlDeleteCriticalSection+0x122, calling ntdll!ExpInterlockedPushEntrySList
000000000da2e760 000007fef5a53b54 clr!operator delete+0x14, calling clr!EEHeapFreeInProcessHeap
000000000da2e780 000007fef5a7fcd5 clr!ETW::MethodLog::MethodJitting+0x31, calling clr!GetThread
000000000da2e790 000007fef5a605f4 clr!ListLockEntry::`scalar deleting destructor'+0x108, calling clr!operator delete
000000000da2e7f0 000007fef5a52b2c clr!CrstBase::Enter+0x74, calling ntdll!RtlTryEnterCriticalSection
000000000da2e850 000007fef5a7f25f clr!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker+0x4f1, calling clr!UnsafeJitFunction
000000000da2e960 000007fef5ac3545 clr!MDInternalRO::GetParentToken+0x7d
000000000da2e990 000007fef5a6ba50 clr!validateTokenSig+0xb4, calling clr!CorSigUncompressData
000000000da2e9a0 000007fef5abe0a5 clr!LookupMap<MethodDesc * __ptr64>::GetElement+0x21, calling clr!LookupMapBase::GetElementPtr
000000000da2e9d0 000007fef5abedfa clr!MemberLoader::GetMethodDescFromMethodDef+0x99, calling clr!MethodDesc::CheckRestore
000000000da2eaa0 000007fef5fd3935 clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::CompileMethodDesc+0x66, calling clr!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker
000000000da2eb30 000007fef5fd3a64 clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::JITMethod+0xb4, calling clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::CompileMethodDesc
000000000da2eb70 000007fef5e6f0aa clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::HandleMethodRecord+0x30d382, calling clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::JITMethod
000000000da2ebc0 000007fef5b61d1e clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::PlayProfile+0x126, calling clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::HandleMethodRecord
000000000da2ebe0 00000000775e870a ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0xe2, calling ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext
000000000da2ebf0 000007fef5a53735 clr!GCPreemp::GCPreemp+0xe, calling clr!GetThread
000000000da2ec20 000007fef5b6202a clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::JITThreadProc+0x1ca, calling clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::PlayProfile
000000000da2ec70 00000000775e870a ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0xe2, calling ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext
000000000da2eca0 000007fefa465f08 MSVCR120_CLR0400!control87+0x28, calling MSVCR120_CLR0400!get_fpsr
000000000da2ecb0 00000000770fa47f kernel32!QueryPerformanceCounter+0xf, calling ntdll!ZwQueryPerformanceCounter
000000000da2ede0 000007fef5a52ba4 clr!ClrFlsIncrementValue+0x18, calling clr!ClrFlsGetBlock
000000000da2ee40 000007fef5a58f13 clr!ThreadStore::UnlockThreadStore+0x53, calling clr!ClrFlsIncrementValue
000000000da2eeb0 000007fef5b62193 clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::StaticJITThreadProc+0x78, calling clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::JITThreadProc
000000000da2ef00 000007fef5b9fcb6 clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
000000000da2efb0 00000000770fa199 kernel32!BaseDllInitialize+0x750, calling kernel32!_security_check_cookie
000000000da2f1c0 00000000775eb9eb ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x163, calling ntdll!memset
000000000da2f200 000007fefd6d1407 crypt32!I_RegStoreDllMain+0x23, calling crypt32!I_ProtectedRootDllMain
000000000da2f280 00000000775eb9eb ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x163, calling ntdll!memset
000000000da2f2d0 000007fef8ed7f38 dssenh!DllMain+0xf8, calling kernel32!TlsSetValue
000000000da2f300 000007fef8eeaa51 dssenh!CRT_INIT+0x2a5, calling dssenh!DllMain
000000000da2f320 000007fefa96138e mscoreei!CRT_INIT+0x135, calling kernel32!GetCurrentThreadId
000000000da2f350 000007fefa9611ee mscoreei!__DllMainCRTStartup+0x8a, calling mscoreei!DllMain
000000000da2f380 000007fefaaf1476 mscoree!calloc_impl+0x72, calling ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap
000000000da2f3d0 000007fefa465c6e MSVCR120_CLR0400!calloc_impl+0x5d, calling ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap
000000000da2f400 000007fefa465d9b MSVCR120_CLR0400!initptd+0xb7, calling MSVCR120_CLR0400!unlock
000000000da2f420 000007fef94e4d9c clrjit!__DllMainCRTStartup+0x8d, calling clrjit!DllMain
000000000da2f430 000007fefd4952cb bcrypt!DllMain+0x5c, calling kernel32!SetLastError
000000000da2f460 00000000775e0494 ntdll!LdrpInitializeThread+0x269, calling ntdll!RtlLeaveCriticalSection
000000000da2f520 00000000775e0683 ntdll!LdrpInitializeThread+0x143, calling ntdll!RtlActivateActivationContextUnsafeFast
000000000da2f528 00000000775e06b6 ntdll!LdrpInitializeThread+0x181, calling ntdll!RtlDeactivateActivationContextUnsafeFast
000000000da2f560 00000000775c6324 ntdll!LdrpInitialize+0xb4, calling ntdll!ZwTestAlert
000000000da2f610 00000000775c6368 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x18, calling ntdll!ZwContinue
000000000da2fa80 000007fef5b9fc9f clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x66, calling clr!_chkstk
000000000da2fac0 00000000770fa54d kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
000000000da2faf0 00000000775c64d1 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

Got a deadlock again this morning. Here is the dumpstack of the problem thread:

```
    000000000cfec6e0 000007fef5a4a216 clr!ConstructKeyCallbackCompare::UseKeys+0x64, calling MSVCR120_CLR0400!strcmp
    000000000cfec710 000007fef5a4a1b7 clr!EEClassHashTable::ConstructKeyFromData+0xec, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
    000000000cfec750 000007fef5a49d04 clr!NgenHashTable<EEClassHashTable,EEClassHashEntry,4>::FindPersistedEntryByHash+0x55, calling clr!NgenHashTable<StubMethodHashTable,StubMethodHashEntry,2>::PersistedBucketList::GetBucket
    000000000cfec7a0 000007fef5ae3948 clr!ClassLoader::GetClassValue+0x252, calling clr!EEClassHashTable::ConstructKeyFromData
    000000000cfec810 000007fef5ab4c83 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeHandleForTypeKey+0xf5, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeHandleForTypeKey_Body
    000000000cfec8b0 000007fef5b8f297 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefThrowing+0x23b, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeHandleForTypeKey
    000000000cfec910 000007fef5a4a1b7 clr!EEClassHashTable::ConstructKeyFromData+0xec, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
    000000000cfec950 000007fef5a4a630 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeHandleThrowing+0x14f, calling clr!TypeHandle::GetLoadLevel
    000000000cfec9a0 000007fef5ae3948 clr!ClassLoader::GetClassValue+0x252, calling clr!EEClassHashTable::ConstructKeyFromData
    000000000cfeca10 000007fef5ae377c clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing+0x39b, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefThrowing
    000000000cfecb40 000007fef5aad873 clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing+0x1e0, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing
    000000000cfecc10 000007fef5c48bab clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing+0x4f3, calling clr!LookupMapBase::GetElementPtr
    000000000cfecd40 000007fef5ab1a6a clr!SigPointer::GetGenericInstType+0x143, calling clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing
    000000000cfecda0 000007fef5ab16c9 clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing+0x564, calling clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing
    000000000cfecdc0 000007fef5a4e906 clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing+0x4f2, calling clr!_chkstk
    000000000cfecf40 000007fef5aae5fe clr!CExecutionEngine::AcquireLock+0x9b, calling ntdll!RtlTryEnterCriticalSection
    000000000cfecf60 000007fef5ab8d32 clr!MethodTable::MethodDataObject::`vector deleting destructor'+0x3a, calling clr!EEHeapFreeInProcessHeap
    000000000cfecfd0 000007fef5abaaea clr!MDInternalRO::GetTypeSpecFromToken+0xa6
    000000000cfed020 000007fef5ac8ddb clr!MemberLoader::GetDescFromMemberRef+0x62a, calling clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing
    000000000cfed350 000007fef5ac19d9 clr!CEEInfo::resolveToken+0x7fc, calling clr!MemberLoader::GetDescFromMemberRef
    000000000cfed4e0 000007fef5abc7ed clr!FieldSecurityDescriptor::IsTreatAsSafe+0xe, calling clr!FieldSecurityDescriptor::VerifyDataComputed
    000000000cfed5a0 000007fef5c49bd6 clr!CEEInfo::getFieldInfo+0x10dd, calling clr!ClassLoader::CanAccessClass
    000000000cfed5c0 000007fef5abee7d clr!CEEInfo::ConvToJitSig+0x26a, calling clr!SigParser::SkipExactlyOne
    000000000cfed660 000007fef5abee7d clr!CEEInfo::ConvToJitSig+0x26a, calling clr!SigParser::SkipExactlyOne
    000000000cfed740 000007fef5abecf8 clr!CEEInfo::getMethodSig+0x36b, calling clr!CEEInfo::ConvToJitSig
    000000000cfed7e0 000007fef5abecf8 clr!CEEInfo::getMethodSig+0x36b, calling clr!CEEInfo::ConvToJitSig
    000000000cfed880 000007fef94a65d4 clrjit!ReaderBase::getCallSiteSignature+0x50, calling clrjit!CORINFO_SIG_INFO::isVarArg
    000000000cfed8b0 000007fef94d99c4 clrjit!ReaderBase::VerifyIsMethodToken+0x14, calling clrjit!ReaderBase::VerifyToken
    000000000cfed8c0 000007fef94c6279 clrjit!ReaderBase::getCallSiteSignature+0x29, calling clrjit!ReaderBase::getCallSiteSignature
    000000000cfed920 000007fef9451ac5 clrjit!GenIR::GenIR_FgCall+0x334
    000000000cfeda40 000007fef944e512 clrjit!ReaderBase::fgBuildPhase1+0x2a2
    000000000cfedb10 000007fef944897b clrjit!ReaderBase::fgBuildBasicBlocksFromBytes+0x8b, calling clrjit!ReaderBase::fgBuildPhase1
    000000000cfedb60 000007fef944f3d6 clrjit!ReaderBase::buildFlowGraph+0x26, calling clrjit!ReaderBase::fgBuildBasicBlocksFromBytes
    000000000cfedb90 000007fef94502cc clrjit!ReaderBase::MSILToIR+0x9c, calling clrjit!ReaderBase::buildFlowGraph
    000000000cfedbf0 000007fef9453308 clrjit!THX_dop2_ReadProc+0x48, calling clrjit!ReaderBase::MSILToIR
    000000000cfedd50 000007fef945475f clrjit!InitCompilerInstance+0x46f, calling clrjit!THX_NColMdInitialize
    000000000cfeddb0 000007fef94542c9 clrjit!JitContext::GetContext+0x124, calling clrjit!InitCompilerInstance
    000000000cfeddc0 000007fef9447d8c clrjit!THX_dop2+0x8c, calling clrjit!THX_dop2_ReadProc
    000000000cfede40 000007fef945410b clrjit!PreJit::compileMethod+0x67, calling clrjit!PreJit::jitCompile
    000000000cfedec0 000007fef5a6f643 clr!invokeCompileMethodHelper+0x7f
    000000000cfedee0 000007fef5abbb99 clr!ClassLoader::CanAccessClass+0x176
    000000000cfedf10 000007fef5a6f56f clr!invokeCompileMethod+0x8f, calling clr!invokeCompileMethodHelper
    000000000cfedf60 000007fef5a70d4b clr!EEJitManager::setBoundaries+0x986, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
    000000000cfedf80 000007fef5a6f45e clr!CallCompileMethodWithSEHWrapper+0x46, calling clr!invokeCompileMethod
    000000000cfedfe0 000000007741a47f kernel32!QueryPerformanceCounter+0xf, calling ntdll!ZwQueryPerformanceCounter
    000000000cfee010 000007fef5a6f325 clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0x9bb, calling clr!CallCompileMethodWithSEHWrapper
    000000000cfee190 000000007764b431 ntdll!RtlpFreeHeap+0x9df, calling ntdll!RtlpDeCommitFreeBlock
    000000000cfee300 000007fef9463f04 clrjit!THX_makeEA+0x18c, calling clrjit!THX_immed
    000000000cfee420 000007fef5ab8683 clr!TokenSecurityDescriptor::ReadSecurityAttributes+0xa3, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
    000000000cfee460 000007fef5aad8b5 clr!SigPointer::GetTypeHandleThrowing+0x25d, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
    000000000cfee4b0 0000000077649075 ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x1a2, calling ntdll!RtlpFreeHeap
    000000000cfee520 000007fef5abdd28 clr!MethodSecurityDescriptor::ComputeCriticalTransparentInfo+0x468, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
    000000000cfee580 000007fef5a43605 clr!MetaSig::Init+0xc4, calling clr!SigParser::SkipExactlyOne
    000000000cfee590 000007fef9444a14 clrjit!operator delete+0x14, calling clr!EEHeapFreeInProcessHeap
    000000000cfee5f0 000007fef5abe690 clr!Module::GetIL+0x41, calling clr!PEDecoder::CheckILMethod
    000000000cfee620 000007fef5ab2909 clr!ClassLoader::CanAccessClass+0x99, calling clr!MethodTable::GetAssembly
    000000000cfee670 000007fef5b23208 clr!MethodDesc::IsVerifiable+0xb0, calling clr!UnsafeJitFunction
    000000000cfee710 000007fef5b233ff clr!IsTransparentMethodSafeToSkipVerification+0x8c, calling clr!MethodDesc::IsVerifiable
    000000000cfee7c0 000007fef5b22fcf clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0xd5e, calling clr!IsTransparentMethodSafeToSkipVerification
    000000000cfee810 000007fef5ab692d clr!MethodTableBuilder::CopyExactParentSlots+0x2cd
    000000000cfeebd0 000007fef5ab6287 clr!MethodTable::DoFullyLoad+0x5e0, calling clr!MethodTable::SetIsFullyLoaded
    000000000cfeecb0 0000000077625bda ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+0x9a, calling ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection
    000000000cfeecf0 0000000077648bfa ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0xe2, calling ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext
    000000000cfeed20 0000000077625a73 ntdll!RtlDeleteCriticalSection+0x122, calling ntdll!ExpInterlockedPushEntrySList
    000000000cfeed30 000007fef5a43b54 clr!operator delete+0x14, calling clr!EEHeapFreeInProcessHeap
    000000000cfeed50 000007fef5a6fcd5 clr!ETW::MethodLog::MethodJitting+0x31, calling clr!GetThread
    000000000cfeed60 000007fef5a505f4 clr!ListLockEntry::`scalar deleting destructor'+0x108, calling clr!operator delete
    000000000cfeedc0 000007fef5a42b2c clr!CrstBase::Enter+0x74, calling ntdll!RtlTryEnterCriticalSection
    000000000cfeee20 000007fef5a6f25f clr!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker+0x4f1, calling clr!UnsafeJitFunction
    000000000cfeef30 000007fef5ab3545 clr!MDInternalRO::GetParentToken+0x7d
    000000000cfeef60 000007fef5a5ba50 clr!validateTokenSig+0xb4, calling clr!CorSigUncompressData
    000000000cfeef70 000007fef5aae0a5 clr!LookupMap<MethodDesc * __ptr64>::GetElement+0x21, calling clr!LookupMapBase::GetElementPtr
    000000000cfeefa0 000007fef5aaedfa clr!MemberLoader::GetMethodDescFromMethodDef+0x99, calling clr!MethodDesc::CheckRestore
    000000000cfef070 000007fef5fc3935 clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::CompileMethodDesc+0x66, calling clr!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker
    000000000cfef100 000007fef5fc3a64 clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::JITMethod+0xb4, calling clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::CompileMethodDesc
    000000000cfef130 00000000776148ff ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext+0xa38, calling ntdll!RtlpAllocateAffinityIndex
    000000000cfef140 000007fef5e5f0aa clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::HandleMethodRecord+0x30d382, calling clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::JITMethod
    000000000cfef190 000007fef5b51d1e clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::PlayProfile+0x126, calling clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::HandleMethodRecord
    000000000cfef1b0 0000000077648bfa ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0xe2, calling ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext
    000000000cfef1c0 000007fef5a43735 clr!GCPreemp::GCPreemp+0xe, calling clr!GetThread
    000000000cfef1f0 000007fef5b5202a clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::JITThreadProc+0x1ca, calling clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::PlayProfile
    000000000cfef240 0000000077648bfa ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0xe2, calling ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext
    000000000cfef270 000007fee0e85f08 MSVCR120_CLR0400!control87+0x28, calling MSVCR120_CLR0400!get_fpsr
    000000000cfef280 000000007741a47f kernel32!QueryPerformanceCounter+0xf, calling ntdll!ZwQueryPerformanceCounter
    000000000cfef3b0 000007fef5a42ba4 clr!ClrFlsIncrementValue+0x18, calling clr!ClrFlsGetBlock
    000000000cfef410 000007fef5a48f13 clr!ThreadStore::UnlockThreadStore+0x53, calling clr!ClrFlsIncrementValue
    000000000cfef480 000007fef5b52193 clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::StaticJITThreadProc+0x78, calling clr!MulticoreJitProfilePlayer::JITThreadProc
    000000000cfef4d0 000007fef5b8fcb6 clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
    000000000cfef850 000007fef5b8fc9f clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x66, calling clr!_chkstk
    000000000cfef890 000000007741a54d kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
    000000000cfef8c0 0000000077626861 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

Thank you in anticipation..

Comment: `bcrypt!DllMain` is on the stack. This seems to be a loader lock deadlock. You are calling bcrypt with PInvoke, right?

Comment: Thanks . How is a loader lock deadlock resolved ? We are not calling bcrypt in code.Not sure if it gets called internally in a third party library

Comment: No DllMain here. Multicore JIT is on the stack both times. I'd say it's a multicore JIT bug. Report it and disable the multicore JIT profile.

Comment: Thanks usr. That is very much possible. All our other clients are on 4.0 and this has not happened for them. This is the only client on 4.5.2 and i see that multicore JIT is a 4.5 feature. I am asking them to rollback to 4.0 and test again

Answer (score 0):

We did not hear any complaints yet after rollback to .Net 4.0 
So I think that fixed it.